# for loop for cross tabulation

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to create a loop to have R create 3 cross tabulations. Below is my code

```
l=c("nationality", "sex_at_birth", "education")
for (i in l){
 mytables<-(table(HIV_coded$sexual_identity, (HIV_coded[,i]))
 print(mytables)
 }
```

below is my error message

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
" mytables<-(table(HIV_coded$sexual_identity, (HIV_coded[,i]))
 print"
>  }
Error: unexpected '}' in " }"
```

IF i run the same loop, but without trying to cross tabulate the loops work fine.

Thank you,

K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is an extra bracket in the second line

```
  mytables<-(table(HIV_coded$sexual_identity, (HIV_coded[,i]))
            ^
```

which should be

```
mytables <- table(HIV_coded$sexual_identity, HIV_coded[,i])
```

---

If we are storing the output, the `mytables` is updated on each iteration.  instead we can create a `list` and assign the output to `list` elements

```
mytables <- setNames(vector('list', length(l)), l)
for(l1 in l) {
     mytables[[l1]] <- table(HIV_coded$sexual_identity, HIV_coded[,l1])
  }
```